# Network Error 0x7b when running angular on IE

Tags: angular, internet-explorer, xmlhttprequest

I'm using IE11.
My angular application works on Chrome and Firefox.

When I trigger a Http Request on my app I get this error

```
SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x7b, The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
file : search
```

`http://localhost:4200/search` is actual path.

when I click on 
`file : search` I get in debugger this message `Error when open http://localhost:4200/search (this message appear when I trigger the HTTP service)`

I have added some `meta` on index.html but no result

```
<!DOCTYPE  html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the solution

In my code I make a call to server ip this way  `http:///IP.com` ( 3 slashs )

changing it to `http://IP.com` solved the error.